# Display WooCommerce product description and additional information horizontally in the same tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I'm having trouble getting my product page to display correctly.

I'm hoping to try and get a result like this on my product page. (Description & attributes horizontal in same tab)

[image]

---

As you can see in the picture the description is on the left and the attributes show on the right.

On my site, I have currently removed the attributes tab and have it nested underneath the description, using this code in my `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'exetera_custom_product_tabs', 98 );
function exetera_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
        
    // Custom description callback.
    $tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
        global $post, $product;


        // Display the content of the Description tab.
        the_content();


        // Display the heading and content of the Additional Information tab.

        echo '<h2>Specifications</h2>';

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );
    };

    // Remove the additional information tab.
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );

    return $tabs;
}
```

Just can't figure out how to get it to sit horizontally next to each other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the content of the tabs in divs and then align/style them with CSS.
However, this is theme dependent and so my answer is reduced to the absolute basics.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'exetera_custom_product_tabs', 98, 1 );
function exetera_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) { 
    // Custom description callback.
    $tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
        global $post, $product;

        echo '<div class="description left" style="float:left;width:49%;">';

        // Display the content of the Description tab.
        the_content();
        
        echo '</div>';

        // Display the heading and content of the Additional Information tab.

        echo '<div class="specifications right" style="float:right;width:49%;">';

        echo '<h2>Specifications</h2>';

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );
        
        echo '</div>';
    };

    // Remove the additional information tab.
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );

    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: Dude, thanks heaps! That works like a treat, 

As a follow up would there be an easy way to allow it to scale back to vertical for mobile view? or when the screen gets to a particular size? 

Really appreciate the help so far with this though!

Comment: @KaiCraig Your additional questions are certainly possible and the answers are based on applying the correct CSS. However, the general rule on SO is one question at a time. Additional questions that you need help with can therefore always be posted as new questions. Regards